# mysqli_num_rows() always throws error

Tags: php, mysql

i have already searched everywhere but could not find a solution for the problem.
i have a login script in php.When there are no matches in the database for user entered values, an error message is displayed.But also another warning is being thrown.

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, 
boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 26
```

Here's the code. i know that a similar question has been asked many times,but none of them could provide me the solution.Here's the entire code.

```
    <?php

    session_start();
    require_once('connectionvariables.php');
    $error_msg = "";

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
     {
      if(!empty($_COOKIE['user_id']) && !empty($_COOKIE['username']))
        {
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
     }
     else
      {
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
         {
          $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
        $user_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['username']));
        $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['password']));

        if(!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password))
        {
            $query = "SELECT user_id,username FROM mismatch_user WHERE username =       '$user_username' AND password = SHA('$user_password')";
            $data = mysqli_query($dbc,$query); 
            if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1)
            {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                setcookie('user_id',$row['user_id'],time() + ( 60 * 60 * 3600));
                setcookie('username',$row['username'],time() + ( 60 * 60 * 3600));
                header('Location: http://www.google.com');    

            }
            else
            {
                $error_msg = 'enter a valid username and password';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $error_msg = 'you have to enter username and password to Log In...';
        }
    }
   }
}
?>
```

Here's the line 26.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1)
```

Comment: Can you edit your code example to show which is line 26?

Comment: @@saladin akara ..
added the line  causing error.

Comment: can't find affected_rows function. but i think your query fails and therefore its not a mysql resource, its a boolean. Just check whether $data is a boolean befor continue.  and check your query

Comment: i also tried  'mysqli_affected_rows()'
function but the same error is being displayed

Comment: The warning says complains about `mysqli_affected_rows()`, but no call to that function appears in your code.  Please show the full contents of `C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Comment: i am sorry..i posted the wrong warning..I initially used 
mysqli_num_rows()             .it did not work.so used 
mysqli_affected_rows()  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely an error in your query. For example, an unknown column name or similar issue will let `mysqli_query` return `false` (a boolean). I suggest you double check your query's contents to fix any typo. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php for more details.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it, was just checking the docs to make sure I was right.